# Google.map marker info link not working in chrome browser

Tags: c#, google-maps, dictionary

I have use google.maps api and marker locate on given Latitude and Longitude position. On mouseover open one div in which have some of information regarding location and link for that.

Here, I have issue in below code is that, link of URL work in firefox perfectly but not work into chrome browser. I have use chrome 24.0 version.

### I have search lots of link regarding that but i didn't get solution. If you have please provide proper solution.

```
marker = createInfoMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude , Longitude))
marker.setMap(map);

function createInfoMarker(a, b, url)
{
var i = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: a,
        map: map
    });

google.maps.event.addListener(i, "mouseover", function () {
        var info = '<table width="300" style="max-width:500px;background:#fff;border:solid 1px #ddd;"><tr class="vProductItems"><td class="thumbSetting">' +
                            '<div class="thumbTitle nomargin pull-l" style="width:auto;">' +

                                '<span class="pull-r"><a href="' + URL + '"">' + CLICK + '</a></span>' +

                           '</div></td>' +
                        '</tr></table>';
i.openExtInfoWindow(map, info);
});
return i
}
```

Comment: How is that question C# related? For me, this looks more like a javascript problem...

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem? Or enough code to replicate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
marker = createInfoMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude , Longitude))
marker.setMap(map);
var current = null;
function createInfoMarker(a, b, url)
{
var i = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: a,
        map: map
    });

google.maps.event.addListener(i, "mouseover", function () {
        var info = '<table width="300" style="max-width:500px;background:#fff;border:solid 1px #ddd;"><tr class="vProductItems"><td class="thumbSetting">' +
                            '<div class="thumbTitle nomargin pull-l" style="width:auto;">' +

                                '<span class="pull-r"><a href="' + URL + '"">' + CLICK + '</a></span>' +

                           '</div></td>' +
                        '</tr></table>';
 if (current != null)
        { current.close(); }
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        infowindow.setContent(info);
        infowindow.open(map, i);
        current = infowindow;
});
return i
}
```